# How to pass a form select tag selected option to be selected in another page to already be selected when a button is clicked?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to transfer select tag selected option on clicking a button to go to another page where the previously selected option to already be selected. I am doing it in laravel is there a way to do it.

my index.blade.php:

```
  <section class="all-slide-carousel-caption">
    <div class="container">
    <form action="{{url('/booking')}}" class="package-reservation">
        <select name="packageType" id="Package_Type" class="dynamic" data-dependent="Package_Name">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Select Package Type</option>
          @foreach($package_list as $list)
          <option value="{{ $list->Package_Type}}">{{ $list->Package_Type }}</option>
          @endforeach
         </select>
         <select name="packageName" id="Package_Name" class="dynamic">
          <option value="">Select Package</option>
         </select>
         @csrf
          <div class="reservation-button">
            <a href="{{ url('/booking') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold">Booking</button></a>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </section>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.dynamic').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
    var select = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = $(this).val();
    var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $.ajax({
      url:"{{ route('index.fetch') }}",
      method:"POST",
      data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
      success:function(result)
      {
        $('#'+dependent).html(result);
      }
    })
  }
  });

  $('#Package_Type').change(function(){
  $('#Package_Name').val('');
  });
});
</script>
```

My indexController:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $banners = banner::all();
        $WhyWithUs = WhyWithUs::all();
        $package = Package::all();
        $package_list = DB::table('packages')
        ->groupBy('Package_Type')
        ->get();
        $testimonials = testimonials::all();
        return view('pages.index',compact('banners','testimonials','package','WhyWithUs'))->with('package_list', $package_list);
        
    }
    function fetch(Request $request)
    {
     $select = $request->get('select');
     $value = $request->get('value');
     $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
     $data = DB::table('packages')
       ->where($select, $value)
       ->groupBy($dependent)
       ->get();
     $output = '<option value="" disabled selected >Select  '.str_replace('_',' ',$dependent).'  </option>';
     foreach($data as $row)
     {
      $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
     }
     echo $output;
    }
}
```

My booking.blade.php where i want it to be selected in when i press booking button in index.blade.php:

```
  <section id="booking-form" class="mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold text-capitalize">Flight Booking</h1>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Please enter the details below:</p>
            <form action="post" class="booking-form">
                <div class="personal-details">
                    <legend>&nbspPersonal Details&nbsp</legend>
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputname">Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputname" placeholder="Name"  required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputnumber" class="font-weight-bold">Phone Number *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputnumber" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="country" class="font-weight-bold">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" placeholder="Country">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="package-details">
                    <legend>&nbspPackage Details&nbsp</legend>
                    <div class="package-reservation form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <select name="packageType" id="Package_Type" class="dynamic" data-dependent="Package_Name" required>
                                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Package Type</option>
                                @foreach($package_list as $list)
                                <option value="{{ $list->Package_Type}}">{{ $list->Package_Type }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <select name="packageName" id="Package_Name" class="dynamic" required>
                                <option value="">Select Package</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        @csrf
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label font-weight-bold" for="gridCheck">
                        I accept the <a href="#" class="text-primary">Terms and Conditions</a>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="book" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send a form by clicking the button. Then when the function is called return a view and pass the already selected option.

```
return view('booking')->with(['selected_package_type' => $request->packageType]);
```

And then in booking.blade.php

```
<select name="packageType" id="Package_Type" class="dynamic" data-dependent="Package_Name" required>
     <option value="" disabled>Select Package Type</option>
     @foreach($package_list as $list)
        <option @if($list->Package_Type == $selected_package_type) selected @endif value="{{ $list->Package_Type}}">
           {{ $list->Package_Type }}
        </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: i have added my code above can you tell me how i can do it in my code.

Comment: okey i added `@if($list->Package_Type == $selected_package_type) selected @endif` to the selection, was that the needed stuff?

Comment: i need to pass the `return view('booking')->with(['selected_package_type' => $request->packageType]);` in the fetch function is that correct?

Comment: the return view booking.. has to be in the function that gets called when a get request is sent with the url /booking, but in my way its not done with javascript. Why do you want to do it with javascript?

Comment: that javascript is so that the package name will not show at first but on the basis of which package type i choose it will show the packages of that type of my database i was nust asking if i need to write that return view in booking controller or indexcontroller of mine.